# Notepad++ RegEx remove between tags when word matched

Tags: regex, notepad++, kml

I had a similiar question that was used for numbers this time I need to use it for keyword. Below is the sample data that I'm using from a KML file. I would like to remove all placemarks that contain the word footway.

```
 <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#nothing</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
            <SchemaData>
                <SimpleData>highway</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>0.0000,0.0000,0</coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>     
    <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#nothing</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
            <SchemaData>
                <SimpleData>footway</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>0.0000,0.0000,0</coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```

I tried to use the following however it is capturing everything

```
(?i)<Placemark>.*?footway.*?</Placemark>
```

Below is my notepad++ settings

```
Find what: (?i)<Placemark>.*?footway.*?</Placemark>
Replace with:
Warp around
Search Mode: Regular expression & mathces newline
```

Comment: You want to remove the complete `Placemark` tag, right? Seems to be working with my Notepad++. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes I want to remove the tag as well. I'm using verison 6.9.1. I'm unable to upgrade beyond this verison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- Find what: `<Placemark>(?:(?!<Placemark).)*footway(?:.(?!<Placemark))*</Placemark>`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`

This will replace all `<Placemark>` blocks that contain `footway` and only them.

`(?!<Placemark)` is a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that assumes there're no `<Placemark>` before `footway`, so, when you have many `<Placemark>`'s the regex matches a single `<Placemark>` at a time.

`(?:(?!<Placemark).)*` is a non capture group, that occurs 0 or more times and does not contain `(?!<Placemark)` followed by a character.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with Notepad++ 6.9.2. It also works in this online python regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/BYGvzo/1

Are you sure you have the correct options (`regular expression` + `. matches newline`) set?

EDIT: Well, after your edit that's a different story! Not sure how to achieve it with a regex. I think it would be way easier to parse the XML and then get rid of the nodes containing the word footway.

See why: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The problem that I see is that it matches everything until it reaches footway. https://regex101.com/r/BYGvzo/2

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your file, it looks like the first line below and your regular expression is matching as per the second line

```
<Placemark> ... </Placemark> <Placemark> ...footway ... </Placemark>
<Placemark>    .*?                          footway .*? </Placemark>
```

Need to prevent the first `</Placemark>` being included in the match.

If this is a one-off or seldom needed process then an approach I sometime use as it is very adaptable is as follows. Find a single character that does not occur anywhere in the file. For this example `=` is used. Do a replace-all of the regular expression `(</?p)(lacemark>)` with `\1=\2`. Leading to the text:

```
<P=lacemark> ... </P=lacemark> <P=lacemark> ...footway ... </P=lacemark>
```

Then do a replace-all with the regular expression `<P=lacemark>[^=]*footway[^=]*</P=lacemark>` with nothing. Finally, remove all the `=` characters with another replace-all.

If there is no easy to use single character (i.e. something instead of the `=`) then precede the above steps with some replacements to create an unused character. For example first replace all `&` with `&amp;` then replace all `=` with `&eq;`. Now the `=` is free for use. After the above steps, undo the replacements, first replace all `&eq;` with `=` then replace all `&amp;` with `&`.